# is there a way to vote up or down just only once in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following codes were taken from Code Academy's AngularJS lesson. In lesson one, a rating option was offered to the user as 'like' or 'dislike'. Once the user clicks on 'like' button the vote goes up and likewise the user clicks on 'dislike' button the vote added to minus. But there's no way in the code to restrict a user votes up or down just only once.  Is there a way to restrict user voting only once using AngularJS?

html code

```html
<div class="rating">
        <p class="likes" ng-click="plusOne($index)">+{{product.likes}}</p>
        <p class="dislikes" ng-click="minusOne($index)">-{{product.dislikes}}</p>
</div>
```

AngularJS code

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Top Sellers in Books in this Great City';
    $scope.promo = 'Our Christmas Promo is on the way!';
    $scope.products = [{
      name: 'The Book of Trees',
      price: 19,
      pubdate: new Date('2014', '03', '08'),
      cover: 'img/the-book-of-trees.jpg',
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    }, {
      name: 'Program or be Programmed',
      price: 8,
      pubdate: new Date('2013', '08', '01'),
      cover: 'img/program-or-be-programmed.jpg',
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    }, {
      name: 'Book1',
      price: 8,
      pubdate: new Date('2015', '04', '02'),
      cover: 'img/..',
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    }, {
      name: 'Book2',
      price: 8,
      pubdate: new Date('2015', '09', '09'),
      cover: 'img/..',
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    }];
    $scope.plusOne = function(index) {
      $scope.products[index].likes += 1;
    };
    $scope.minusOne = function(index) {
      $scope.products[index].dislikes += 1;
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just mark the object in the array.

```
$scope.plusOne = function(index) {
    if(!$scope.products[index].upvoted){
      $scope.products[index].likes += 1;
      $scope.products[index].upvoted = true;
    }
};
$scope.minusOne = function(index) {
    if(!$scope.products[index].downvoted){
      $scope.products[index].dislikes += 1;
      $scope.products[index].downvoted = true;
    }
};
```

You'll have to add in a slight bit more if you want an upvote to negate a downvote (or vice-versa), but that's trivial.